# How to combine multiple returned SQL rows into one string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have a system where users can submit an article (basically any length of text), and when it's submitted to the database, it's broken down into paragraphs and placed into its own `paragraphs` table. The second table is the `articles` table, which contains `article_id (primary key)`, `title (title of article)`, and `idUsers (id of user that submitted article)`. 
I'm able to successfully submit the data into the tables, but when I query to try to get the paragraphs, using:

```
$q = "SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, paragraphs.paragraph, articles.date, articles.idUsers FROM articles JOIN paragraphs ON articles.article_id = paragraphs.article_id WHERE idUsers = '$idUsers' AND articles.article_id = '$article_id'";
$r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
```

There are multiple rows that are returned, each giving the same information (except for the paragraphs column, which has its unique paragraph text. But the title and date are returned twice). This is what I expected, but I don't want to return everything twice. For example, if there were two paragraphs in the article, one saying `"random text 1"` and the other saying `"random text 2"`, those would both be returned, which is good, but the `article_id`, `article_title`, and `articles.date`, etc., would also be returned in each row along with the unique paragraph text. This means that when I echo out all of these values, everything is echoed twice. When I put these values inside of a `<div></div>`, like so,

```
echo '<div class="get-article-container">';
echo '<div id="articleTitle">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
echo '<div id="articleContents">'.$row['paragraph'].'</div>';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['article_id'].'" class="article_id_value">';
echo '</div>';
```

it creates two `divs` instead of one because multiple rows are being returned. I want to combine the `$row['paragraph']` values to put together all the text in the article in one div, but it should be in one div, not two. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have all these `echo` lines in a loop?

Comment: can you post existing and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by formatting the values before and then echo them
Even if you skip the empty check, it will return the same result as title and article id is the same across all the returned rows.

```
foreach($r as $row){
  (!$title)?$title=$row['title']:$title;
  $paragraph .= '<p>'.$row['paragraph'].'</p>';
  (!$articleId )?$articleId =$row['article_id']:$articleId ;
  $articleId = $row['article_id'];
}

echo '<div class="get-article-container">';
echo '<div id="articleTitle">'.$title.'</div>';
echo '<div id="articleContents">'.$paragraph .'</div>';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$articleId .'" class="article_id_value">';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: This worked, but it also gave me this error: Notice: Undefined variable: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\Real Website\includes\articles\get_articles.php on line 15. It also said that for the variable paragraph on the next line. Any ideas?

Comment: @CarsonD You just need to initialize the variable empty before the loop.

    $title = ""; 
    $paragraph = "";
    $articleId = "";

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reduce() the result of your query into a list of objects like:

```
result {
    article_title,
    article_id,
    paragraphs[]
}
```

then you can echo articleContents with the list of paragraphs of each article

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you do it in two steps.

1. To fetch articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.date, articles.idUsers
2. To fetch paragraphs.paragraph

So for point 1,

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.date, articles.idUsers 
  FROM articles 
  JOIN paragraphs 
    ON articles.article_id = paragraphs.article_id 
 WHERE idUsers = '$idUsers' 
   AND articles.article_id = '$article_id'";
```

And for point 2,

```
SELECT  paragraphs.paragraph 
  FROM articles 
  JOIN paragraphs 
    ON articles.article_id = paragraphs.article_id 
 WHERE idUsers = '$idUsers' 
     AND articles.article_id = '$article_id'";
```

Hope this would solve your issue.